# Can I program the Arduino without having an actual board with the able to emulate a COM connection to the computer?

Tags: led, motor, communication, emulation

I have ordered my Arduino, but it is not going to arrive until 2 months, and I would like to be able to emulate a COM connection to the emulated Arduino. I am writing a program that listens on the com port, and would like to test it.

The program needs to run on Windows, and emulate a COM connection, and a breadboard with a LED, and motors on it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Simulator](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/simulator/simulator.wb_Simulator_Use.html) in [Atmel Studio](http://www.atmel.com/microsite/atmel_studio6/) or something like [Virtual Breadboard](http://www.virtualbreadboard.com/) which looks good

The [Atmel Studio](http://www.atmel.com/microsite/atmel_studio6/) simulator might take a bit of work to simulate your devices but if you have 2 months then maybe that's okay :) If you want to use the simulator in Atmel Studio then you might also find the [Arduino plugin for Atmel Studio](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/Arduino-for-Atmel-Studio.aspx) useful.

I think there are quite a few other solutions if you search google.

Answer (score -1):

To verify communication via COM port (to send messages as well as to receive) you can use arduino emulator from wokwi.com

with the Wokwi arduino emulator, it is easy to do the changes, add input devices as well.

**To create a COM port**
You just need to have a

```
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Text message");
```

you will be able to see the virtual serial window in the bottom right where you can see the messages printed out as well as you will be bale to key in the serial data you want to send to Arduino.
[image]